# Locating the "read tcp" error in the Go source code

Tags: go, tcp, reverse-proxy

I am getting a network error of the form

```
http: proxy error: read tcp [...]->[...]: i/o timeout
```

And want to locate specifically the source of the `read tcp` error in the Go source code. Could anyone help me with that?

Comment: Possibly a lot of places. Possibly nowhere (it could be from the underlying OS lib). Why do you need to find this? If your issue is that you're encountering the error, that issue is probably easier to find help with.

Comment: @ThunderCat Can you post you comment as an answer? Seems like the right one.

Comment: @Adrian Posted a more fleshed-out question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53950606/getting-sporadic-http-proxy-error-read-tcp-i-o-timeout-on-heroku

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `read tcp [...]->[...]: i/o timeout` error is generated [here](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/b115207baf6c2decc3820ada4574ef4e5ad940ec/src/net/net.go#L179).  The underlying timeout error is defined [here](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/b115207baf6c2decc3820ada4574ef4e5ad940ec/src/internal/poll/fd.go#L37).